# Implementing monero accepting for online merchant with monero-python

Tags: payment-integration

I am trying to understand monero & recieve funds with monero using [this python api](https://pypi.org/project/monero-python/) in my website.

Please check with my plan and correct me freely if I'm wrong.

1. For every account I will make a sub-address like the following and save it with user info

   ```
   w = Wallet(JSONRPCWallet(port=28088)) 
   w.new_address() #create new subaddress for a wallet

   new_address_for_user = w.get_addresses()[-1] #get the newly created subaddress
   user_info['monero_subaddress'] = new_address_for_user #save the subaddress with user info
   ```
2. If user buys an item, check for the transaction

   ```
   w = Wallet(JSONRPCWallet(port=28088)) 
   monero_subaddress_for_user = user_info['monero_subaddress']
   incoming = w.incoming(local_address=monero_subaddress_for_user)[-1] # get transaction with the particular subaddress in user_info

   price_of_item = transaction_info['price']

   if price_of_item is incoming.amount:
       #check user paid for item correctly
   ```

Stepping aside bugs and other things for later, is this code the right **concept** for basic transaction with monero?

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, yes. The defaults for `wallet.incoming` return confirmed transactions. Depending on the rest of your architecture, you may want to make use of unconfirmed transactions (e.g. mark product as sold but not ship until the transaction is confirmed), if this is the case you'll need to also make use of the parameters for incoming: `wallet.incoming(unconfirmed=True, confirmed=False)`.